# MSTest - A window in the solution will not show

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a test project in Visual Studio 2015. I created another project within this solution with a window. I would like to show the window prior to the unit test beginning, however, it hangs on the "ShowDialog" and never shows the window. Wheres the Class Initialization for test:

```
public class ProdButtonTests {

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Setup(TestContext context){
        FrmMain _testwindow = new FrmMain();

        _testwindow.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

I have a reference to the forms project, and it all compiles cleanly, but it will not show the window.

Comment: Is this a coded UI test? Otherwise, I would never, ever mix UI with a unit test.

Comment: MsTest uses multiple threads to do its work and you can't guarantee the thread type (STA or MTA) you will be on when running your testing code. My guess is that you are running on a thread without a message pump and something is getting stuck waiting for events to pump.